# BST Insertion issue

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

My code for BST insertion is getting passed for 3 test cases and is failing for other 3 test cases, as the test case are hidden I can't figure out where I'm going wrong with my logic. Please check and advise me what other different test case my logic will not pass.
here's code:

```
/*
Node is defined as 

typedef struct node
{
   int data;
   node * left;
   node * right;
}node;

*/


node * insert(node * root, int value)
{ node* n;
 n=root;
 if(n!=NULL)   
 {while (true )  
   { if(n->data > value && n->left!=NULL){n=n->left;}
      else if(n->data < value && n->right!=NULL){n=root->right;}
      else 
            {  node* a=new node();
             a->data=value;
           if(n->data > value ){ n->left=a;break; }
           else{ n->right=a;break; }
            }
   }
 }
 else
 {node* a=new node();
  a->data=value;
  root=a;   
 }
return root;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I write it like

```
node*  insert(node * root, int value)
    { node* n=  root;
       node* a=new node();
      if( a == NULL )
    { cout<<" no memory  \n " ; exit(0); } 
       a->data=value;
       a->left=a->right=NULL;
     if(n!=NULL)   
     {while (true )  
       { if(n->data > value  )
             {   if( n->left!=NULL )   
                              {n=n->left;} 
                 else 
                     { 
                          n->left=a; 
                          return root; 
                      }                     
               }
          else if(n->data < value  )
              {  if (  n->right!=NULL ) 
                           {n=n->right;}
                 else  
                      {
                         n->right = a;
                         return root;
                        }
              }

       }
     }
     else
     { 
    return  a;   
     } 
    }
```

Comment: Ashraf : the function declaration is implicitly declared by the problem setter, I can't modify it.

Comment: Ok  I reWritet  the function    again for   For you Ashish   any help I 'm ready in data structure

Comment: Thank's Ashraf, but I'm not looking for the solution, instead  my doubt is what are the possible test case where my code is failing to produce the correct result, if u can help me with this thing I'll be really grateful to you! thanks in advance!